Creating yes and no columns from multiple variable columns in R with percentages
I have 5 columns each for a different variable and the values can either be "yes", "no" or "unknown". I want to create a flextable that shows the variable as the row and "yes", "no", and "unknown" as the columns with counts and percentages.
ID    Temp   Cough   Runny nose  Weight loss   Chills
1     Yes    No      Yes         No            Yes
2     Yes    Yes     Unknown     Yes           Yes
3     Yes    Unknown No          No            No
4     Yes    Yes     Yes         Yes           Yes
5     No     No      No          No            No

What I would like the output to look like is:
              Yes     No      Unknown
             n   %    n  %     n   %
Temp         4  80    1  20    0   0
Cough        2  40    1  20    2   40
Runny Nose   2  40    2  40    1   20
Weight Loss  2  40    3  60    0   0
Chills       3  60    2  40    0   0

I know I need to use pivot and summarize to create the counts, but I am getting confused about how to map the variables and then how to create the double row headings and calculate percentages.

You can use gtsummary for this utlising tbl_summary with percent="row":
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

pivot_longer(df, cols=-ID) |>
  mutate(name=factor(name, levels=names(df)[-1]),
                     value=factor(value, 
                     levels=c("Yes","No", "Unknown"))) |>
  tbl_summary(include=-ID, by=value, percent="row") |>
  as_flex_table()



df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Temp = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No"), Cough = c("No", "Yes", "Unknown", "Yes", "No"), Runny.nose = c("Yes", 
"Unknown", "No", "Yes", "No"), Weight.loss = c("No", "Yes", "No", 
"Yes", "No"), Chills = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))


One alternative is using tidyverse:
data |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Response") |> 
  count(Variable, Response) |> 
  group_by(Variable) |> 
  mutate(Total = sum(n), `%` = (n / Total) * 100) |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Response, 
    values_from = c(n, `%`),
    names_glue = "{Response}_{.value}",
    values_fill = list(n = 0, `%` = 0)  
  ) |> 
  select(
    Variable,
    starts_with("Yes_"),
    starts_with("No_"),
    starts_with("Unknown_")
  ) |> 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 × 7
    Variable    Yes_n `Yes_%`  No_n `No_%` Unknown_n `Unknown_%`
  <chr>       <int>   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>     <int>       <dbl>
1 Chills          3      60     2     40         0           0
2 Cough           2      40     2     40         1          20
3 Runny.nose      2      40     2     40         1          20
4 Temp            4      80     1     20         0           0
5 Weight.loss     2      40     3     60         0           0


Comparing data with answer using ==, do calculations and cbind.
> f <- \(ans) {
+   tb <- t(apply(+(dat[-1] == ans), 2, \(x) {
+     s <- sum(x)
+     c(s, s*100/(length(x)))
+   }))
+   tb |>
+     `dimnames<-`(list(colnames(dat[-1]), paste0(ans, '_', c('n', '%'))))
+ }
> lapply(unique(unlist(dat[-1])) |> setNames(nm=_), f) |> do.call(what='cbind')
            Yes_n Yes_% No_n No_% Unknown_n Unknown_%
Temp            4    80    1   20         0         0
Cough           2    40    2   40         1        20
Runny.nose      2    40    2   40         1        20
Weight.loss     2    40    3   60         0         0
Chills          3    60    2   40         0         0


Data:
> dput(dat)
structure(list(ID = 1:5, Temp = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No"), Cough = c("No", "Yes", "Unknown", "Yes", "No"), Runny.nose = c("Yes", 
"Unknown", "No", "Yes", "No"), Weight.loss = c("No", "Yes", "No", 
"Yes", "No"), Chills = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))


You can use as_flextable() with the result of a table()
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Temp = c(
  "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes",
  "No"
), Cough = c("No", "Yes", "Unknown", "Yes", "No"), Runny.nose = c(
  "Yes",
  "Unknown", "No", "Yes", "No"
), Weight.loss = c(
  "No", "Yes", "No",
  "Yes", "No"
), Chills = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -5L
))

x <- pivot_longer(df, cols = -ID) |>
  mutate(
    name = factor(name, levels = names(df)[-1]),
    value = factor(value, levels = c("Yes", "No", "Unknown"))
  )
with(x, table(name, value)) |>


  as_flextable(
    include.row_percent = TRUE,
    include.column_percent = FALSE,
    include.table_percent = FALSE
  )



